# Friend Request via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As I understand it, the Facebook Graph API doesn't support adding friends. Also, the old Facebook API's are being phased out.

Is there anyway to add friends (friend request) by email address via any Facebook API that will be compatible going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to send a friend request via any API, regardless of having the user's contact information. This is by design to prevent abuse of the feature.